# Unable to downgrade MySQL from version 8 to 5.6 nor start MySQL (MySQL Error Log Included)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, ssh

I run a Plesk VPS (**OS:**  Centos 6/Linux (Final)), whereby I recently tried to upgrade the MySQL from version 5.5.55 to version 5.6.

Being relatively new to this area, I strictly followed this [Plesk Article](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213403429-How-to-upgrade-MySQL-5-5-to-5-6-5-7-or-MariaDB-5-5-to-10-0-10-1-10-2-on-Linux-)  Specifically following the steps within the 'Plesk on CentOS 6' Tab.

Unfortunately, I made the mistake of assuming version 8 was disabled as default.  As a result, MySQL version 8 was installed and is now causing me major issues.  To the point, where I cannot start MySQL.

I have tried to downgrade, from version 8 to version 5.6, by opening the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo` Notepad++, where I ensured the below was entered:

```
# Enable to use MySQL 5.5
[mysql55-community]
name=MySQL 5.5 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.5-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

# Enable to use MySQL 5.6
[mysql56-community]
name=MySQL 5.6 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.6-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

# Enable to use MySQL 5.7
[mysql57-community]
name=MySQL 5.7 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.7-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql80-community]
name=MySQL 8.0 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql-connectors-community]
name=MySQL Connectors Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql-tools-community]
name=MySQL Tools Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql-tools-preview]
name=MySQL Tools Preview
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-preview/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql-cluster-7.5-community]
name=MySQL Cluster 7.5 Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-cluster-7.5-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql-cluster-7.6-community]
name=MySQL Cluster 7.6 Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-cluster-7.6-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

Upon entering the command `yum update mysql`, the following appeared on the screen:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www4.atomicorp.com
 * epel: mirror.freethought-internet.co.uk
 * remi-safe: mirror.netweaver.uk
Package(s) mysql available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for Update
```

I then continued with the steps, in the hope that the installation would still miraculously work somehow.

I got as far as `service mysqld start` where I generated the same error as before, which was:

```
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

I am not just absolutely stumped as to how to downgrade to MySQL version 5.6 and to start back up MySQL.

**MySQL Log:**

```
[Warning] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
[System] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) starting as process 14057
[System] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
[ERROR] [InnoDB] Unsupported redo log format (0). The redo log was created before MySQL 5.7.9
[ERROR] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
[ERROR] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
[ERROR] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
[ERROR] [Server] Aborting
[System] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.16)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

**Additional Information:**

I am not sure if the below helps but after entering the command `yum repolist all | grep mysql`, the following information appeared:

```
mysql-cluster-7.5-community MySQL Cluster 7.5 Community          disabled
mysql-cluster-7.6-community MySQL Cluster 7.6 Community          disabled
mysql-connectors-community  MySQL Connectors Community           enabled:     94
mysql-tools-community       MySQL Tools Community                enabled:     78
mysql-tools-preview         MySQL Tools Preview                  disabled
mysql55-community           MySQL 5.5 Community Server           disabled
mysql56-community           MySQL 5.6 Community Server           enabled:    512
mysql57-community           MySQL 5.7 Community Server           disabled
mysql80-community           MySQL 8.0 Community Server           disabled
```

**Version 8 References**

As per the advise in the Comment section, I have performed the command `yum list mysql*` as to generate the following results as to identify any relevant 'version 8 packages' to be removed.  The only problem is, I am not sure which are 'version 8 packages':

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                                            |  30 kB     00:00
 * atomic: www4.atomicorp.com
 * epel: mirror.freethought-internet.co.uk
 * remi-safe: mirror.netweaver.uk
PLESK_17_8_11-extras                                     | 2.9 kB     00:00
PLESK_17_8_11-extras/primary_db                          |  32 kB     00:00
PLESK_17_PHP56                                           | 2.9 kB     00:00
PLESK_17_PHP56/primary_db                                |  14 kB     00:00
PLESK_17_PHP70                                           | 2.9 kB     00:00
PLESK_17_PHP70/primary_db                                |  15 kB     00:00
PLESK_17_PHP73                                           | 2.9 kB     00:00
PLESK_17_PHP73/primary_db                                |  17 kB     00:00
atomic                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00
atomic/primary_db                                        | 651 kB     00:00
epel                                                     | 5.3 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db                                          | 6.1 MB     00:00
mysql-connectors-community                               | 2.5 kB     00:00
mysql-connectors-community/primary_db                    |  37 kB     00:00
mysql-tools-community                                    | 2.5 kB     00:00
mysql-tools-community/primary_db                         |  50 kB     00:00
mysql56-community                                        | 2.5 kB     00:00
mysql56-community/primary_db                             | 261 kB     00:00
plesk-migrator                                           | 2.9 kB     00:00
plesk-migrator/primary_db                                | 6.7 kB     00:00
plesk-migrator-tp                                        | 2.9 kB     00:00
plesk-migrator-tp/primary_db                             | 1.2 kB     00:00
remi-safe                                                | 3.0 kB     00:00
remi-safe/primary_db                                     | 1.2 MB     00:00
Available Packages
mysql.i686                       5.5.44-30.el6.art                        atomic
mysql.x86_64                     5.5.55-1659.el6.art                      atomic
```

Comment: Downgrading from 8.0 is not supported.  Or at least not easily.

Answer (score 0):

`yum update` will only replace an installed package with a newer version unless you tell it otherwise, so it won't downgrade your 8.0 installation even if the repository it came from has been disabled in its config files.

I would suggest uninstalling the current version with `yum remove` and then installing the version you want. Make sure to protect the data files themselves and/or make copies. Use `yum list mysql*` or `yum list installed | grep mysql` to see what you have installed and what versions and then remove anything version 8 related with `yum remove packagename`.

#### Example

```
yum remove mysql-community-client
```

> **Important:**
> Make a note of them so you know what to install from 5.6.

The challenge you're having with 8.0 is that going straight there from 5.5 is too big a jump for the updates needed to the data files. Each new version only understands the file formats from a certain range of older versions.

I had problems with 8.0.16 too - I ended up reinitialising the database and then loading a mysqldump from the earlier version as it was the quickest way to get up and running.

Comment: I have now been able to Start MySQL, after reinstalling the relevant packages.  I have noticed that the Webmail page is now displaying an Apache Test Page with the domain itself displaying an 'Internal Server Error' message.  Is this is sign of an error or is it a waiting game for variables to propagate etc?